# Decode large base64 string

Tags: android, base64

I have created a base64 string from a picture on the SD card using this(below) code, and it works but when I try to decode it (even further below) I get a `java.lang.outOfMemoryException`, presumably because I am not splitting the string into a reasonable size before I decode it as I am before I encode it.

```
byte fileContent[] = new byte[3000];
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
try{
     FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(sel);
     while(fin.read(fileContent) >= 0) {
    b.append(Base64.encodeToString(fileContent, Base64.DEFAULT));
     }
}catch(IOException e){

}
```

The above code works well, but the problem comes when I try to decode the image with the following code;

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(img.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
ImageView image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
image.setImageBitmap(
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
);
```

I have tried this way too

```
byte[] b = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now I assume that I need to split the string up into sections like my image encoding code, but I have no clue how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need decode the image in Background thread like AsyncTask
or
you need reduce your image quality using BitmapFactory .
Example:

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            options.inPurgeable=true;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Your image exact loaction",options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object 

        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problem

- base64 encoding requires much more space. 3 bytes convert to 4 chars (Factor 8/3)
- you read the whole file at once

in same way your first approach solved this issues. So just use that version

By that way, why are you using **decodeByteArray** and not **decodeFile**

Comment: I am using decode byte array because after I encode the picture, I don't put it in a file, I store it in a static variable, and then access from my next activiyt

Comment: In some way, depends on concrete implementation. decodeFile doesnot need a (huge) byte array, it is likely that the native (C++?) implementation is much more memory effient

Answer (score 1):

You might try to decode to a temporary file and create image from that file.

As to base64, it is 6 bits per character, or 6x4=24 bits=3 bytes per 4 characters.
So if you take 4 characters of base64, you will not break the corresponding 3 bytes.
That is, you may split the base64-encoded data at character indices that are a multiple of 4.

Comment: Creating a temporary file sounds like it might work, I will give that a shot